# Acces file from Azure Data Lake sensitive storage by databricks

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake, sensitive-data

I m accesing to files in the normal storage by the following method:

```
input_path = "my_path"
file= "file.mp3"
path = os.path.join(path_data, file)
full_path = '/dbfs/' + path

with open(full_path, mode='rb') as file: # b is important -> binary
    fileContent = file.read()
```

I am not able to use the same method in **sensitive storage**

I am aware that sensitive storage have another way to acces data

```
path_sensitive_storage = 'mypath_sensitive'
```

If I use spark it works perfectly, but i am interested in not using spark read but open file

```
input_df = (spark.read
            .format("binaryFile")
            .option("header", "true")
            .option("encoding", "UTF-8")
            .csv(full_path)
            )
```

There is a way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Azure Data Lake as a source, you need to mount the container in Databricks DBFS by using OAuth method. Once the container is mounted, you can use it.

Use the code below to mount the container.

```
configs = {"fs.azure.account.auth.type": "OAuth",
       "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
       "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id": "ba219eb4-0250-4780-8bd3-d7f3420dab6d",
       "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": "0wP8Q~qWUwGSFrjyByvwK-.HjrHx2EEvG06X9cmy",
       "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47/oauth2/token",
       "fs.azure.createRemoteFileSystemDuringInitialization": "true"}

dbutils.fs.mount(
source = "abfss://sample11@utrolicstorage11.dfs.core.windows.net/",
mount_point = "/mnt/sampledata11",
extra_configs = configs)
```

Once mounted, you can use below code to list the files in mounted location.

```
dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/sampledata11/")
```

And finally use `with open` statement to read the file

```
with open("/dbfs/mnt/sampledata11/movies.csv", mode='rb') as file: # b is important -> binary
    fileContent = file.read()
    print(fileContent)
```

Check the image below for the complete implementation and the outputs below.

[image]

Comment: the solution worked for me, I forgot to thank you, Thank you very much !!

Comment: Great. Good to hear that. Your welcome!